Ubuntu Studio 22.04 will not upgrade to 24.04
Ubuntu Studio 22.04.04 will not upgrade to 24.04. What should I do?


$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for onno: 
Hit:1 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                            
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
8 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libflashrom1 libftdi1-2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  vlc-plugin-qt libvlc5 libimage-magick-perl vlc-data libvlccore9 libheif1 vlc
  imagemagick vlc-bin libpathplan4 vlc-l10n liblua5.4-0 graphviz libavdevice58
  libgvpr2 libgvc6 libdcmtk16 ffmpeg libopenexr25 libmagick++-6.q16-8
  libpostproc55 libcgraph6 libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra vlc-plugin-samba
  libcdt5 libavcodec58 libimage-magick-q16-perl libmagickwand-6.q16-6
  vlc-plugin-notify libavutil56 imagemagick-6.q16 libswscale5 libeditorconfig0
  libmagickcore-6.q16-6 vlc-plugin-access-extra vlc-plugin-skins2 libgsl27
  vlc-plugin-video-splitter liblab-gamut1 libswresample3 imagemagick-6-common
  vlc-plugin-video-output libavformat58 libgslcblas0 libde265-0 libvlc-bin
  vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-visualization libavfilter7
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
The following packages have been kept back:
  python3-update-manager update-manager-core
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apparmor libapparmor1 libapparmor1:i386 libssl3 libssl3:i386 openssl ubuntu-advantage-tools
  ubuntu-pro-client ubuntu-pro-client-l10n
9 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
6 standard LTS security updates
Need to get 5,954 kB of archives.
After this operation, 13.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 libssl3 i386 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.18 [1,947 kB]
Get:2 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libssl3 amd64 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.18 [1,905 kB]
Get:3 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 libapparmor1 i386 3.0.4-2ubuntu2.3build2 [41.1 kB]
Get:4 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libapparmor1 amd64 3.0.4-2ubuntu2.3build2 [39.2 kB]
Get:5 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 openssl amd64 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.18 [1,184 kB]
Get:6 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-pro-client-l10n amd64 33.2~22.04 [20.2 kB]
Get:7 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-pro-client amd64 33.2~22.04 [211 kB]
Get:8 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-advantage-tools all 33.2~22.04 [10.9 kB]
Get:9 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 apparmor amd64 3.0.4-2ubuntu2.3build2 [595 kB]
Fetched 5,954 kB in 8s (734 kB/s)                                                                            
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 455379 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-libssl3_3.0.2-0ubuntu1.18_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libssl3:i386 (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.17), to allow configuration of libssl3:amd64 (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.17) ...
Unpacking libssl3:amd64 (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.18) over (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.17) ...
Preparing to unpack .../1-libssl3_3.0.2-0ubuntu1.18_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libssl3:i386 (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.18) over (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.17) ...
Preparing to unpack .../2-libapparmor1_3.0.4-2ubuntu2.3build2_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libapparmor1:amd64 (3.0.4-2ubuntu2.3), to allow configuration of libapparmor1:i386 (3.0.4-2ubuntu2.3) ...
Unpacking libapparmor1:i386 (3.0.4-2ubuntu2.3build2) over (3.0.4-2ubuntu2.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../3-libapparmor1_3.0.4-2ubuntu2.3build2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libapparmor1:amd64 (3.0.4-2ubuntu2.3build2) over (3.0.4-2ubuntu2.3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../4-openssl_3.0.2-0ubuntu1.18_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openssl (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.18) over (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.17) ...
Preparing to unpack .../5-ubuntu-pro-client-l10n_33.2~22.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-pro-client-l10n (33.2~22.04) over (32.3.1~22.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../6-ubuntu-pro-client_33.2~22.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-pro-client (33.2~22.04) over (32.3.1~22.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../7-ubuntu-advantage-tools_33.2~22.04_all.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-advantage-tools (33.2~22.04) over (32.3.1~22.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../8-apparmor_3.0.4-2ubuntu2.3build2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apparmor (3.0.4-2ubuntu2.3build2) over (3.0.4-2ubuntu2.3) ...
Setting up libapparmor1:amd64 (3.0.4-2ubuntu2.3build2) ...
Setting up libapparmor1:i386 (3.0.4-2ubuntu2.3build2) ...
Setting up libssl3:amd64 (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.18) ...
Setting up libssl3:i386 (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.18) ...
Setting up apparmor (3.0.4-2ubuntu2.3build2) ...
Reloading AppArmor profiles 
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
Setting up openssl (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.18) ...
Setting up ubuntu-pro-client (33.2~22.04) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/apparmor.d/ubuntu_pro_apt_news ...
Setting up ubuntu-pro-client-l10n (33.2~22.04) ...
Setting up ubuntu-advantage-tools (33.2~22.04) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.8) ...


what is "non-Ubuntu deb-packaged software" please? I never "enabled" sources for software.

Now you are down to two upgrades, both of which are in Phased Updates. You can wait a few days for phasing to complete, or you can override the phasing and install right now. Your choice. Then the release-upgrade will work.

thank you very much! i will wait a few days and try again...

...still nothing: https://onno.gt/www/ubuntu20240915.png

That looks like a different problem. Please open a new question with all-new apt update and apt upgrade output.

okay thank you, i wil.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1527072/ubuntu-studio-22-04-will-not-upgrade-to-24-04-different-problem
Why is this at all happening?
