Ubuntu Studio 22.04 will not upgrade to 24.04 different problem

sudo apt update
[sudo] password for onno: 
Hit:1 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [129 kB]
Get:3 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [128 kB]               
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages [1,806 kB]
Hit:5 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                       
Get:6 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages [701 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main i386 Packages [539 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main Translation-en [295 kB]     
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [13.3 kB]    
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages [902 kB]               
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe i386 Packages [627 kB]        
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [19.3 kB]              
Get:13 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [2,058 kB]                      
Get:14 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main Translation-en [355 kB]                        
Get:15 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [17.8 kB]                 
Get:16 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [2,495 kB]                
Get:17 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted Translation-en [429 kB]                  
Get:18 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1,124 kB]                  
Get:19 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe i386 Packages [732 kB]                     
Get:20 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe Translation-en [261 kB]                    
Get:21 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [26.2 kB]             
Fetched 12.7 MB in 20s (625 kB/s)                                                                            
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
30 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
onno@Carillion:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libflashrom1 libftdi1-2 linux-headers-5.15.0-119 linux-headers-5.15.0-119-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  vlc-plugin-qt libvlc5 libimage-magick-perl vlc-data libvlccore9 libheif1 vlc
  imagemagick vlc-bin libpathplan4 vlc-l10n liblua5.4-0 graphviz libavdevice58
  libgvpr2 libgvc6 libdcmtk16 ffmpeg libopenexr25 libmagick++-6.q16-8
  libpostproc55 libcgraph6 libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra vlc-plugin-samba
  libcdt5 libavcodec58 libimage-magick-q16-perl libmagickwand-6.q16-6
  vlc-plugin-notify libavutil56 imagemagick-6.q16 libswscale5 libeditorconfig0
  libmagickcore-6.q16-6 vlc-plugin-access-extra vlc-plugin-skins2 libgsl27
  vlc-plugin-video-splitter liblab-gamut1 libswresample3 imagemagick-6-common
  vlc-plugin-video-output libavformat58 libgslcblas0 libde265-0 libvlc-bin
  vlc-plugin-base vlc-plugin-visualization libavfilter7
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-5.15.0-121-lowlatency linux-headers-5.15.0-122 linux-headers-5.15.0-122-generic
  linux-image-5.15.0-121-lowlatency linux-lowlatency-headers-5.15.0-121 linux-modules-5.15.0-121-lowlatency
The following packages have been kept back:
  apparmor libapparmor1 libapparmor1:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apt apt-utils base-files libapt-pkg6.0 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4 libcurl4:i386 libpython3.10
  libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib linux-headers-generic linux-headers-lowlatency
  linux-image-lowlatency linux-libc-dev linux-lowlatency python-apt-common python3-apt python3-distupgrade
  python3-pkg-resources python3-setuptools python3-update-manager python3.10 python3.10-minimal
  ubuntu-drivers-common ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt update-manager-core
27 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
10 standard LTS security updates
Need to get 141 MB of archives.
After this operation, 685 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 base-files amd64 12ubuntu4.7 [61.9 kB]
Get:2 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libapt-pkg6.0 amd64 2.4.13 [912 kB]
Get:3 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 apt amd64 2.4.13 [1,363 kB]
Get:4 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 apt-utils amd64 2.4.13 [211 kB]
Get:5 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libpython3.10 amd64 3.10.12-1~22.04.6 [1,949 kB]
Get:6 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 python3.10 amd64 3.10.12-1~22.04.6 [509 kB]
Get:7 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libpython3.10-stdlib amd64 3.10.12-1~22.04.6 [1,850 kB]
Get:8 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 python3.10-minimal amd64 3.10.12-1~22.04.6 [2,258 kB]
Get:9 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libpython3.10-minimal amd64 3.10.12-1~22.04.6 [814 kB]
Get:10 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 python-apt-common all 2.4.0ubuntu4 [14.6 kB]
Get:11 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 python3-apt amd64 2.4.0ubuntu4 [164 kB]  
Get:12 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-drivers-common amd64 1:0.9.6.2~0.22.04.7 [59.0 kB]
Get:13 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 python3-setuptools all 59.6.0-1.2ubuntu0.22.04.2 [340 kB]
Get:14 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 python3-pkg-resources all 59.6.0-1.2ubuntu0.22.04.2 [133 kB]
Get:15 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt all 1:22.04.20 [5,684 B]
Get:16 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core all 1:22.04.20 [26.2 kB]
Get:17 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 python3-distupgrade all 1:22.04.20 [106 kB]
Get:18 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 python3-update-manager all 1:22.04.21 [39.1 kB]
Get:19 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 update-manager-core all 1:22.04.21 [11.5 kB]
Get:20 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libcurl3-gnutls amd64 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.18 [284 kB]
Get:21 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 libcurl4 amd64 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.18 [289 kB]
Get:22 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 libcurl4 i386 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.18 [320 kB] 
Get:23 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-lowlatency-headers-5.15.0-121 all 5.15.0-121.131 [12.3 MB]
Get:24 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-5.15.0-121-lowlatency amd64 5.15.0-121.131 [2,864 kB]
Get:25 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-5.15.0-122 all 5.15.0-122.132 [12.3 MB]
Get:26 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-5.15.0-122-generic amd64 5.15.0-122.132 [2,827 kB]
Get:27 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-generic amd64 5.15.0.122.122 [2,294 B]
Get:28 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-5.15.0-121-lowlatency amd64 5.15.0-121.131 [86.2 MB]
Get:29 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-image-5.15.0-121-lowlatency amd64 5.15.0-121.131 [11.6 MB]
Get:30 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-lowlatency amd64 5.15.0.121.110 [1,696 B]
Get:31 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-image-lowlatency amd64 5.15.0.121.110 [2,378 B]
Get:32 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-lowlatency amd64 5.15.0.121.110 [2,272 B]
Get:33 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 5.15.0-122.132 [1,322 kB]
Fetched 141 MB in 4min 20s (544 kB/s)                                                                        
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 455555 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../base-files_12ubuntu4.7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking base-files (12ubuntu4.7) over (12ubuntu4.6) ...
Setting up base-files (12ubuntu4.7) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/issue ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/issue.net ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/lsb-release ...
motd-news.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
(Reading database ... 455555 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libapt-pkg6.0_2.4.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libapt-pkg6.0:amd64 (2.4.13) over (2.4.12) ...
Setting up libapt-pkg6.0:amd64 (2.4.13) ...
(Reading database ... 455555 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../archives/apt_2.4.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apt (2.4.13) over (2.4.12) ...
Setting up apt (2.4.13) ...
(Reading database ... 455555 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-apt-utils_2.4.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apt-utils (2.4.13) over (2.4.12) ...
Preparing to unpack .../01-libpython3.10_3.10.12-1~22.04.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.10:amd64 (3.10.12-1~22.04.6) over (3.10.12-1~22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../02-python3.10_3.10.12-1~22.04.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.10 (3.10.12-1~22.04.6) over (3.10.12-1~22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../03-libpython3.10-stdlib_3.10.12-1~22.04.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.10-stdlib:amd64 (3.10.12-1~22.04.6) over (3.10.12-1~22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../04-python3.10-minimal_3.10.12-1~22.04.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.10-minimal (3.10.12-1~22.04.6) over (3.10.12-1~22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../05-libpython3.10-minimal_3.10.12-1~22.04.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.10-minimal:amd64 (3.10.12-1~22.04.6) over (3.10.12-1~22.04.5) ...
Preparing to unpack .../06-python-apt-common_2.4.0ubuntu4_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-apt-common (2.4.0ubuntu4) over (2.4.0ubuntu3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../07-python3-apt_2.4.0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-apt (2.4.0ubuntu4) over (2.4.0ubuntu3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../08-ubuntu-drivers-common_1%3a0.9.6.2~0.22.04.7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-drivers-common (1:0.9.6.2~0.22.04.7) over (1:0.9.6.2~0.22.04.6) ...
Preparing to unpack .../09-python3-setuptools_59.6.0-1.2ubuntu0.22.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-setuptools (59.6.0-1.2ubuntu0.22.04.2) over (59.6.0-1.2ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../10-python3-pkg-resources_59.6.0-1.2ubuntu0.22.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-pkg-resources (59.6.0-1.2ubuntu0.22.04.2) over (59.6.0-1.2ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../11-ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt_1%3a22.04.20_all.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt (1:22.04.20) over (1:22.04.19) ...
Preparing to unpack .../12-ubuntu-release-upgrader-core_1%3a22.04.20_all.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (1:22.04.20) over (1:22.04.19) ...
Preparing to unpack .../13-python3-distupgrade_1%3a22.04.20_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-distupgrade (1:22.04.20) over (1:22.04.19) ...
Preparing to unpack .../14-python3-update-manager_1%3a22.04.21_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-update-manager (1:22.04.21) over (1:22.04.19) ...
Preparing to unpack .../15-update-manager-core_1%3a22.04.21_all.deb ...
Unpacking update-manager-core (1:22.04.21) over (1:22.04.19) ...
Preparing to unpack .../16-libcurl3-gnutls_7.81.0-1ubuntu1.18_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.18) over (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.17) ...
Preparing to unpack .../17-libcurl4_7.81.0-1ubuntu1.18_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libcurl4:i386 (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.17), to allow configuration of libcurl4:amd64 (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.17) ...
Unpacking libcurl4:amd64 (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.18) over (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.17) ...
Preparing to unpack .../18-libcurl4_7.81.0-1ubuntu1.18_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libcurl4:i386 (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.18) over (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.17) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-lowlatency-headers-5.15.0-121.
Preparing to unpack .../19-linux-lowlatency-headers-5.15.0-121_5.15.0-121.131_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-lowlatency-headers-5.15.0-121 (5.15.0-121.131) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-5.15.0-121-lowlatency.
Preparing to unpack .../20-linux-headers-5.15.0-121-lowlatency_5.15.0-121.131_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.15.0-121-lowlatency (5.15.0-121.131) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-5.15.0-122.
Preparing to unpack .../21-linux-headers-5.15.0-122_5.15.0-122.132_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.15.0-122 (5.15.0-122.132) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-5.15.0-122-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../22-linux-headers-5.15.0-122-generic_5.15.0-122.132_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.15.0-122-generic (5.15.0-122.132) ...
Preparing to unpack .../23-linux-headers-generic_5.15.0.122.122_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-generic (5.15.0.122.122) over (5.15.0.119.119) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-5.15.0-121-lowlatency.
Preparing to unpack .../24-linux-modules-5.15.0-121-lowlatency_5.15.0-121.131_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-5.15.0-121-lowlatency (5.15.0-121.131) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-5.15.0-121-lowlatency.
Preparing to unpack .../25-linux-image-5.15.0-121-lowlatency_5.15.0-121.131_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-5.15.0-121-lowlatency (5.15.0-121.131) ...
Preparing to unpack .../26-linux-lowlatency_5.15.0.121.110_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-lowlatency (5.15.0.121.110) over (5.15.0.119.109) ...
Preparing to unpack .../27-linux-image-lowlatency_5.15.0.121.110_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-lowlatency (5.15.0.121.110) over (5.15.0.119.109) ...
Preparing to unpack .../28-linux-headers-lowlatency_5.15.0.121.110_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-lowlatency (5.15.0.121.110) over (5.15.0.119.109) ...
Preparing to unpack .../29-linux-libc-dev_5.15.0-122.132_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.15.0-122.132) over (5.15.0-119.129) ...
Setting up python3-pkg-resources (59.6.0-1.2ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
Setting up linux-lowlatency-headers-5.15.0-121 (5.15.0-121.131) ...
Setting up apt-utils (2.4.13) ...
Setting up python3-setuptools (59.6.0-1.2ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.15.0-122.132) ...
Setting up libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.18) ...
Setting up linux-headers-5.15.0-121-lowlatency (5.15.0-121.131) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.15.0-121-lowlatency
   ...done.
Setting up libpython3.10-minimal:amd64 (3.10.12-1~22.04.6) ...
Setting up python-apt-common (2.4.0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up libcurl4:amd64 (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.18) ...
Setting up libcurl4:i386 (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.18) ...
Setting up linux-headers-5.15.0-122 (5.15.0-122.132) ...
Setting up linux-headers-lowlatency (5.15.0.121.110) ...
Setting up python3-apt (2.4.0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up linux-headers-5.15.0-122-generic (5.15.0-122.132) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.15.0-122-generic
   ...done.
Setting up linux-headers-generic (5.15.0.122.122) ...
Setting up python3.10-minimal (3.10.12-1~22.04.6) ...
Setting up libpython3.10-stdlib:amd64 (3.10.12-1~22.04.6) ...
Setting up libpython3.10:amd64 (3.10.12-1~22.04.6) ...
Setting up python3.10 (3.10.12-1~22.04.6) ...
Setting up ubuntu-drivers-common (1:0.9.6.2~0.22.04.7) ...
Setting up linux-image-5.15.0-121-lowlatency (5.15.0-121.131) ...
I: /boot/vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to vmlinuz-5.15.0-119-lowlatency
I: /boot/initrd.img.old is now a symlink to initrd.img-5.15.0-119-lowlatency
I: /boot/vmlinuz is now a symlink to vmlinuz-5.15.0-121-lowlatency
I: /boot/initrd.img is now a symlink to initrd.img-5.15.0-121-lowlatency
Setting up linux-image-lowlatency (5.15.0.121.110) ...
Setting up linux-lowlatency (5.15.0.121.110) ...
Setting up linux-modules-5.15.0-121-lowlatency (5.15.0-121.131) ...
Setting up python3-distupgrade (1:22.04.20) ...
Setting up ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (1:22.04.20) ...
Setting up python3-update-manager (1:22.04.21) ...
Setting up ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt (1:22.04.20) ...
Setting up update-manager-core (1:22.04.21) ...
Processing triggers for install-info (6.8-4build1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.8) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for cracklib-runtime (2.9.6-3.4build4) ...
Processing triggers for plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text (0.9.5+git20211018-1ubuntu3) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.15.0-121-lowlatency (5.15.0-121.131) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.15.0-121-lowlatency
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-121-lowlatency
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-121-lowlatency
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-121-lowlatency
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-121-lowlatency
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-121-lowlatency
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-119-lowlatency
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-119-lowlatency
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-116-lowlatency
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-116-lowlatency
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (22.04) on /dev/sda1
Found Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (14.04) on /dev/sda5
done
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-121-lowlatency

continued from here: Ubuntu Studio 22.04 will not upgrade to 24.04
Thank you very much!

This question is similar to: Ubuntu Studio 22.04 will not upgrade to 24.04. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Add this info to your other question, don't post additional questions on the same problem.

no it is not,
user535733 asked: "That looks like a different problem. Please open a new question with all-new apt update and apt upgrade output."
So i did.
Thank you!

...no ideas any one?

...i am not much of a wizzkid and the problem persists, so would it make sense to manualy download 24 and just overwrite the partition with 22 with it? 22 does not work flawles anyway...
Thank you!
